# How can I correctly parse this kind of date?

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I could not find a correctly and clean working solution for my Date which is formatted like this:

201406082159

(8th of June, 21:59 here)

Last I tried was this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMDDHHMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Sadly it's not working and printing out

```
Sun Dec 29 21:00:00 CET 2013
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Minutes are set up by `m` not `M`

Years are set up by `y` not `Y`

Days (in month) are set up by `d` not `D` (in year)

```
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: aaah, thanks, that's it! Like often I got it ALMOST :-)

Comment: `D` is  Day in year. `d` is day in month.

Comment: I also think it should be CEST 2014 instead of CET 2014. Any possibility to get it?

Comment: CEST means something different to CET (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) You probably actually want British Summer Time (BST), which is in some sense equivalent to CET as they are both UTC+01

Comment: Further note - the time zone abbreviation (CET, BST, GMT) etc will depend on the setup of the computer where you use the code.  E.g. my computer will output `Sun Jun 08 21:59:00 BST 2014` when parsing the given date using the code above. It would give `Wed Jan 08 21:59:00 GMT 2014` if the string was `"201401082159"` Note - this is independent of the `Locale.ENGLISH` which might be confusing at first...

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest having a look at the api of SimpleDateFormat class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

It would help you resolve your current question and you will certainly be able to find the correct pattern in the future if you have a different date format to parse.

Answer (score 0):

You are using outmoded legacy classes. Use java.time classes for your date-time work.

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "201406082159";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmm" );
```

## `LocalDateTime`

Your input lacks information about any offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you know the context of the data intends a certain time zone, apply it. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `CET` or `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zoneId );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.